# What is the IShouldNormalize's alternative in Abp.io?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, abp

I have a project, that created in  **Abp.io** framework. I before used **ASP.NET Boilerplate** framework and ASP.NET Boilerplate has `IShouldNormalize` interface for normalize request's input. But I don't find `IShouldNormalize`'s alternative in Abp.io

What is the `IShouldNormalize`'s alternative in **Abp.io** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No alternative. You can use IValidatableObject for validation and
> simple normalization. You can add your own method and call in the
> application service.
>
> But we suggest you to make it in your application service method
> explicitly

https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/1908

You can use the [`IValidatableObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject?view=net-5.0) for validation and normalization for your needs.

`IValidatableObject` has just a method named **Validate** you can define your normalization rules in here, that you normally do in the **Normalize** method of the`IShouldNormalize` interface.

Comment: Thanks you. But I think it is a violation of SOLID principles (Interface segregation), because validation is different from normalization.